# Remove keybindings in Rider Switcher menu

Tags: rider

[image: Rider Switcher menu]

Is it possible to remove the keyboard shortcuts highlighed in the blue circle, in JetBrains Rider?

Comment: Why do you want to remove them? Do you have any clashes with other shortcuts that you want to use in the Switcher menu?

Comment: Yes, I use Ctrl+N to move downwards in the list, but now the moment I hit "N" I get the Nuget Menu.